# Integral with respect to a measure over a subset

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

The constuction of the integral of a function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb R $ with respect to a measrue $\mu$ i.e. 
$$ \int _X f \mathrm d \mu.$$ 
is well known. I'm wondering what if I want to integrate $f$ over a subset $A \subset X$. Does it make any difference if we define 
$$ \int _A f \mathrm d\mu:=\int _X f  1_A \mathrm d \mu $$ or 
$$ \int _A f \mathrm d \mu:=\int _A f|_A \mathrm d \mu$$?

Comment: I think that it is best to approach this as follows: $A$, as a subset of a measure space $X$, is itself a measure space naturally. Then your second expression is the basic one, expressing what you mean by the integral over $A$ (restrict to $A$ and then take integral in the already defined way). Then, it will be a lemma, that the first expression holds (so not by definition, but as an equality to establish).

Comment: If you want to do the second approach, the most pressing matter is to define the meaning of $\int_A g\,d\mu$ for a function $g:A\to\Bbb R$, since per se $\mu$ is a function from a special subset of $\mathcal P(X)$ to $[0,\infty]$.

Comment: You're right - assuming the second equation as the definition the first one should be a lemma. But I'm confused a little becasue it seems that in our course we tacitly assumed the second equation as definition whereas some sources use the first eqation as definition.